# Android - How to call an intent(activity) inside the onDraw(Canvas) properly?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-canvas, android-context

I'm trying to call an intent inside the canvas but it doesn't seem to work the way I thought it should be. What I have in mind is when it passes through the `startactivity()`, then that's it, it exits the canvas right away but I was wrong.

Flow should be:

```
Menu -> Pong(Activity) -> Canvas -> Game_Over
```

What's happening:

```
Menu -> Pong(Activity) -> Canvas(screen stuck here) -> Game_Over(iterates unknown times)
```

Sometimes it crashes and won't proceed to Game_Over.

Inside my onDraw() is the code below when the **Game Over condition** is met:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), GameOver.class);
i.putExtra("score", Integer.toString(ball.getScore()));
i.putExtra("level", Integer.toString(ball.getLevel()));
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

From what I've observed after making the scores, it seems to be looping for like 20+ times since the toast for the "High Score" found in the next activity won't stop and the screen is stuck at the canvas until the loop stops. This gave me a clue that the activity to be called is looping countless times.

Who's at fault here? Is it the `onDraw()` for redrawing even though it started the `startActivity()` already? If yes, how do I stop `onDraw()` from looping before it reaches intent so it won't loop the next activity?

Here's my `onDraw()`:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Background
    canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    // Score
    canvas.drawText("Score: " + Integer.toString(ball.getScore()), 25, 50,
            paint);

    // Level
    canvas.drawText("Level: " + Integer.toString(ball.getLevel()), 25, 100,
            paint);

    // =========================
    // Draw Paddle
    // paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA00FFFF"));
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(170, 0, 255, 255));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    canvas.drawLine(padX, padY, padX + padWidth, padY, paint);

    // Draw Ball
    canvas.drawCircle(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), BALL_RADIUS, paint);

    if (ball.getScore() % 200 == 0) {
        // counter = counter + 1;
        if (ball.getLevel() < MAX_LEVEL) {
            ball.setSpeedX(ball.getSpeedX() * 0.25f);
            ball.setSpeedY(ball.getSpeedY() * 0.25f);
        }
    }

    postInvalidate();

    if (ball.getY() + (float) BALL_RADIUS >= y - 6) {
        if (ball.getX() + BALL_RADIUS / 2 > padX
                && ball.getX() - BALL_RADIUS / 2 < padX + padWidth) {
            ball.setGameOver(false);
        }

        else {
            ball.setGameOver(true);
            canvas.drawText("Game Over! Please Wait.", x / 2 - 170, y / 3,
                    paint);

            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), GameOver.class);
            i.putExtra("score", Integer.toString(ball.getScore()));
            i.putExtra("level", Integer.toString(ball.getLevel()));
            getContext().startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onDraw can be called 60 times a second, it should just draw, not handle activity flow.
The minimal change is to add a boolean and make sure you call startActivity only once. A better solution is to move the activity managemen out of the drawing, and into a state management logic

Comment: I see, I got it working now, thanks a lot for mentioning "onDraw can be called 60 times a second". I remembered my Python class and the behavior of its canvas(pygame). Thanks again! :D